# Rails 3 Mailer :date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mailer

What is the default for `:date` option set to if none is specified in the mail action?

It should just be `Time.now`, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not set, the header will be set by the delivery agent (generally your SMTP server), so it depends on who you are sending your mail through.  Any good one will use the current server time with the correct offset however.

Comment: Awesome. I would love to see that in the rails source if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I searched the code and couldn't find a reference, but found this relating to rails 2.  http://railsguides.heroku.com/2.3.5/action_mailer_basics.html - the sent_on parameter.